# Does a state need to be entangled for it to produce nonlocal correlations?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, non-locality

I was reading the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_nonlocality) on quantum non-locality and saw this near the bottom:

> While it is true that a pure bipartite quantum state must be entangled in order for it to produce nonlocal correlations, there exist entangled (mixed) states which do not produce such correlations, and there exist non-entangled (namely, separable) states that do produce some type of non-local behavior.

So it says `A state must be entangled in order for it to produce nonlocal correlations` and goes on to say `There exist non-entangled states that do produce some type of non-local behavior`. This seems like a direct contradiction to me, what am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

There is no contradiction because in the quote you mention it is specified that the first implication (nonlocal correlation $\implies$ entanglement) is true for *pure* states, while the second one (non-entanglement can produce nonlocal correlations) is true for *mixed* states.

In other words, there cannot be pure, non-entangled states that produce nonlocal correlations, but there can be *mixed*, non-entangled states that do.